# if time not found it should tell next time available time in log

Tags: bash, function, shell, time, scripting

Is there any time function, which can check the time and if not found tell us the next available date.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p " enter the App name : " app
file="/logs/$app/$app.log"
if ! [ -f "$file" ]; then
    echo "$app.log not found, Please check correct log name in deployer"
    exit
fi

format=$(head -1 $file | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}')
format1=$(tail -1 $file | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}')
read -p " Enter the Date in this Format --'$format' : " first
until grep -q "$first" "$file"
do
  echo "Date not found"
  read -p " Enter the Date in this Format --'$format' : " first
done
final_first=$first
echo "logs are present till this '$format1' date, use this date if you want logs from Provided to latest."
read -p "Enter the end date : " end
until grep -q "$end" "$file"
do
  echo "Date not found"
  read -p "Enter the end date : " end
done
final_end=$end
cd /logs/$app
sed -n " /$final_first/,/$final_end/ "p $file >$app.txt
zip $app.zip $app.txt
rm $app.txt
```

Output is

```
./app_log_extract 
 enter the App name : cspt
 Enter the Date in this Format --'Sep 08 04:53:30' : Sep 08 05
Date not found
 Enter the Date in this Format --'Sep 08 04:53:30' :
```

Now I want along with Date not found it should tell, Log is present from Sep 08 20:09:39

Log file is

```
Sep 08 20:09:39 INFO  [main] common.ComponentManagerImpl - added model class 'com.ge.oilandgas.cspt.model.RoleValidModel' under key 'role-valid'
Sep 08 20:09:39 INFO  [main] common.ComponentManagerImpl - added dispatcher class 'com.ge.casper.servlet.GenericDispatcher' for key 'html'
Sep 08 20:09:39 INFO  [main] servlet.CasperServlet - CASPER is online.
Sep 09 10:57:20 INFO  [http-0.0.0.0-8086-9] model.SessionValidModel - CSPT - User null is logged on!
Sep 09 10:58:49 FATAL [http-0.0.0.0-8086-3] np.dss - UserBeanRepository.query->error in creation of document:
```

AWK tool is mainly used for reporting some data in useful manner. With out these BEGIN and END blocks the output will be meaning less, Here End block is not defined. debug of this code

```
./test
 enter the App name : cspt
++ file=/logs/cspt/cspt.log
++ '[' -f /logs/cspt/cspt.log ']'
+++ head -1 /logs/cspt/cspt.log
+++ awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'
++ format='Sep 08 04:53:30'
+++ tail -1 /logs/cspt/cspt.log
+++ awk '{print $1,$2,$3}'
++ format1='at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) '
++ read -p ' Enter the Date in this Format --'\''Sep 08 04:53:30'\'' : ' first
 Enter the Date in this Format --'Sep 08 04:53:30' : Sep 08 21:19:19
++ grep -q 'Sep 08 21:19:19' /logs/cspt/cspt.log
++ read month_in date_in time_in
++ awk '
BEGIN {
    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",month)
    for (i in month) 
        {
        month_nums[month[i]]=i
        echo "$i"    
        }
}

(month_nums[$1] >= month_in) && ($2>=date_in) && ($3>=time_in)

{
   echo "logs are available from    "
    exit 0;   
}
' month_in=Sep date_in=08 time_in=04:53:30 /logs/cspt/cspt.log
++ echo Sep
Sep
++ echo 08
08
++ echo 04:53:30
04:53:30
```

Comment: Show your log file format... 2-3 lines should help.

Comment: @anishsane done, I need any function which can tell me the next date if present date not found

Comment: @anishsane can u edited my code,  I mean m not getting where this code will be put , is this in until section after the do command

Comment: You should be the best person to know, where you want that print.

Comment: @anishsane I updated the debug of code in Answer section

Comment: No. **You** need to know what you want & where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may help:

```
format="Sep 08 05" # actually, this is swt by user input.

read month_in date_in time_in <<< "$format"
awk '
BEGIN {
    split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",month)
    for (i in month) {
        month_nums[month[i]]=i
    }
}

(month_nums[$1] >= month_nums[month_in]) && ($2>=date_in) && ($3>=time_in){
    print "logs are available from " $1, $2, $3;
    exit 0;   
}
' "month_in=$month_in" "date_in=$date_in" "time_in=$time_in" logfile
```